# Show text box text length on status label

Tags: c#

How can you show the text length in a text box on a status tool strip label? So every time you type 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, it shows the number on the label of characters on the label. So 5. in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a `textbox`'s `textchanged` event. and write this code in it:

```
label1.text = textbox1.Text.Length.ToString();
```

**Complete code:**

```
textBox1.TextChanged +=textBox1_TextChanged;
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.text = textbox1.Text.Length.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `TextLength` property of the `TextBox` control.

So,

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.text = textbox1.TextLength.ToString();

}
```